# Desirable properties of datasets and models for benchmarking Bayesian posterior inference algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, dataset, markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo

Are there canonical datasets for benchmarking the performance of posterior inference algorithms? For example in machine learning literature, the [MNIST dataset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MNIST_database) ([and others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_datasets_for_machine-learning_research)) is often used in benchmarking optizmation algorithms.

If this question does not fit the community guidelines, here's an alternate question:

Which properties are desirable in a dataset and model for a comprehensive assessment of Bayesian posterior inference algorithms?

An example of a desirable property of a dataset and model might be the presence of multiple modes separated by large regions of low density in the posterior. Another example is a high dimensional problem that has been solved.

Looks like [StRD MCMC Dataset](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/strd/mcmc/background.html) had a promising start, but the datasets are very small and dated.

Another example is the collection of oddly-shaped, 2-dimensional posterior distributions seen in this [HMC visualization application](https://chi-feng.github.io/mcmc-demo/app.html). Are there any known datasets/models with properties exhibited in this example but in higher dimensions? Even better if it has known expected values.

Seems like a similar discussion took place: [performance benchmarks for MCMC](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/204559/performance-benchmarks-for-mcmc) (@lacerbi).