# Reversibility in MCMC

Tags: machine-learning, markov-chain-montecarlo, gibbs

I am reading [Geyer's lecture notes](http://www.stat.umn.edu/geyer/f05/8931/n1998.pdf) on MCMC. A condensed version of these notes constitutes Chapter 1 of the Handbook of Markov Chain Monte Carlo (ed. Brooks et al., 2011).

Geyer notes that the *composition* of valid transition operators is still valid:

> It is clear that if an update mechanism $U_1$ preserves
>   a specified distribution, and so does another update mechanism $U_2$, then so
>   does $U_1$ followed by $U_2$, which we will denote $U_1U_2$.

Later on he notes that $U_1U_2$ is in general not reversible, but one could easily build a reversible composite update via a palindromic update, such as $U_1 U_2 U_1$ or $U_1 U_2 U_2 U_1$.

Reversibility is a sufficient condition to prove that a given update leaves the target distribution invariant, and that is why we want elementary updates to be reversible. However, once we prove that, we do not *need* the composite update to be reversible. (For example, the typical fixed-scan Gibbs sampler is not reversible.)

**Is there any theoretical or practical gain in keeping composite updates reversible?**
My question is general, not only for Gibbs; although I suspect that the effect of ordering of operators might have been studied the most in the case of Gibbs sampling.

In practice, I am currently building MCMC updates by composing a number of elementary operators of various kind (see also [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/204522/combining-transition-operators-in-mcmc)).
I *could* combine the operators in a palindromic way -- would that matter?

PS: I am aware that *probabilistic mixtures* of operators are valid and reversible, but here I am interested in composition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am interpreting your question as much more general in that "Is there any gain to using a reversible Markov chain over a non-reversible Markov chain?". Here are two reasons I can think of off the top of my head:

1. **Standard errors:** If the chain is reversible, then a Markov chain CLT can hold for geometrically ergodic Markov chains while assuming only a finite second moment. If the chain is not reversible, then you have to assume $2 + \delta$ for $\delta > 0$ finite moments. So if you are estimating the posterior mean, and have only two finite moments available, then only a nonreversible Markov chain might not allow analysis of standard errors. You can find more information [here](http://users.stat.umn.edu/~galin/clt_fin.pdf).
2. **Spectral Gap:** Often analysis of the convergence rates of MCMC samplers is done by looking at the spectral gap of the Markov chain. For a reversible Markov chain, the second largest eigenvalue determines the mixing time, and there are many known bounds for this. Maybe see a review [here](https://people.cs.umass.edu/~luke/mcmcmixing.pdf). So if your Markov chain is reversible, it is likely easier to study its convergence rates. There is also some work that has been done for non-reversible Markov chains (see [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.5322)), but the literature is not as rich. This is some more discussion on this in [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/179406/markov-chain-monte-carlo-why-is-non-reversible-mc-mc-not-as-popular).

Overall, if you don't have a need to study the exact convergence rate for your sampler, and your distribution is well behaved enough that it has larger than 2 moments for most functions of interest, then there should be no reason to restrict yourself to just reversible Markov chains. This is part of the reason why fixed-scan Gibbs sampler are so often used; in practice nothing is lost.

Comment: (+1) Thanks for the great general answer! Interestingly, the linked MathOverflow question states that "[...] non-reversible (or, irreversible) Markov chains usually converge faster to their invariant distributions. [...]". Is this true, and in which case? Because if this is the case, then it might matter in terms of efficiency whether the composition of operators is reversible or not.

Comment: @lacerbi I found that claim surprising. It is true in my experience that Gibbs sampling often mixes better than M-H, but I would be surprised if there is a general statement of this.